# What is the proper name for "catastrophe style" blocks of content?

Tags: terminology, human-interface-guideline, conventions

We're building a layout for a big newspaper with lots of customizable content blocks for different needs. One of the requests is what they call **"Catastrophe Block"**: *a special block that will show up on front page taking the full width of the layout, with bigger font and abundant use of images and/or infographics.*

Now we're building this section, and I could go with that name, since they are already using it. However, this will be used by 200+ different editors, and the block will be used for any kind of important content, not necessarily a catastrophe. For example: *a sports final, elections, some huge entertainment news (like Oscars awards)* and so on. Besides, I'd like to avoid negative connotations.

**In short:** I can't find a proper name for this (and to make it worse, the newspaper is in English). **What would be the correct name for this kind of section in media industry?**

## EDIT

I'm not looking for opinions. I could call it *"Breaking News"* (which is the taxonomy the element will use). I'm wondering if there's an accepted and DOCUMENTED standard name for this

Comment: It is entirely possible that calling it a "catastrophe block" is industry jargon, in which case you should use it when working in/with that industry. Check with your actual user market to be sure.

Comment: yes, that's what I thought. But I asked the client and the PM said it's how HE and the UI designer calls it, hence why I'm asking if there's an standardized convention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the proper name in journalism industry is redletter:

[source: The News Manual](https://www.thenewsmanual.net/Resources/glossary.html#R)

> An important breaking news story. From the newspaper practice of highlighting an exclusive, breaking news story in red type.

[source: Journalism.uk](https://www.journalism.co.uk/glossary.php)

> Redletter - Exclusive, breaking news coverage of a major news event,
>   printed in red type.

Doing a search on Google, it seems this comes from [Red Letter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter), with 2 possible disambiguation meanings:

1. **[Red Letter Day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter_day)**

> A red letter day (sometimes hyphenated as red-letter day or called
>   scarlet day in academia) is any day of special significance or
>   opportunity. Its roots are in classical antiquity; for instance,
>   important days are indicated in red in a calendar dating from the
>   Roman Republic (509–27 BC). In medieval manuscripts, initial capitals
>   and highlighted words (known as rubrics) were written in red ink. The
>   practice was continued after the invention of the printing press,
>   including in Catholic liturgical books. Many calendars still indicate
>   special dates and holidays in red instead of black.

2. [**Red letter edition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_letter_edition)

> Red letter edition bibles are those in which the Dominical words—those
>   spoken by Jesus Christ, commonly only those spoken during His
>   corporeal life on Earth—are printed rubricated, in red ink. This is a
>   modern practice derived from the art and Roman Catholic practice in
>   mediaeval scriptoria of rubricating headings, leading letters of
>   sectional text, and words of text in manuscripts for emphasis, similar
>   to italicization

## User Testing

With the help of the PM, I surveyed several of the editors (12 editors, 11 completed answers) using open answers and they answered the block should be named as *"breaking news block"* or *"breaking news splash"*, or *"splash block"*.

After that, I did a moderated test with 2 questions:

1. asked what would they think if they see the word **redletter**. Answers were unanimous: *yes, they recognize that word without a doubt*.
2. Asked about what kind of UI element they would expect from that word, all answers were: *a featured breaking news with prominent visuals (size, typography, imagery, etc.)*

Additionally, they all expect the color red to be there somewhere. Most answers specifically said: *White text title on red background*. This is interesting because we didn't consider the color, which is very different to the blue the element will use according to UI provided. I guess it's something we'll need to test out as well

Answer (score 2):

You ask for documented names for this type of content. Twitter's Bootstrap (a very popular CSS/JS framework) uses the term [jumbotron](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/jumbotron/) to describe this kind of content.

[image: Jumbotron example]

Their description of this element is:

> ## Jumbotron
>
> #### Lightweight, flexible component for showcasing hero unit style content.
>
> A lightweight, flexible component that can optionally extend the entire viewport to showcase key marketing messages on your site.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're talking about a ‘News Ticker' or a ‘News Marquee'. Everyone else's suggested terms are still pretty good though.

- **News Ticker**
- News crawler
- News crawl
- News slide
- News Marquee

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/News_ticker

Answer (score 0):

"Above-the-fold hero image space" ?

Answer (score 0):

I've heard

- Masthead
- Hero banner

Answer (score 0):

You could always go with

1. Breaking News
2. Just In
3. Happening Now

In UX terms in the past I have called this

1. Utility Nav/Zone
2. Above the header notification zone